# Как вернуть массив данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Задача выгрузить в excel из бд mysql данные по количеству отработанных часов за месяц на каждый день, т.е. 1.02 - 8 часов и т.д., на н количество людей, скрипт работает но на выходе я получаю только данные по последнему человеку, т.к. при изменении переменной массив перезаписывается, как сделать так чтобы после отработки по каждой из фамилий полученные данные в носились в один многомерный массив

```
$db = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","1234");

mysql_select_db("test",$db);
// получаем массив со всеми сотрудниками
//запрос к базе с именами
$result = mysql_query("SELECT names FROM names");

$dbname = array();
//заполнение массива $dbname
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $dbname = array_merge($dbname, $row);
}
//получение данных на каждый день месяца по конкретному человеку
for($i=0; $i < count($dbname);$i++)
{
    $a = $dbname[$i];//записываем в переменную $a значение из массива  

    $data = array($a);

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT date, hours FROM first WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-02-1' AND '2016-02-10' and names = '$a'");

    while($wor = mysql_fetch_row($res))
        {

            $data = array_merge($data, $wor);

        }

}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: перед for делаем `$data=array();`  в цикле `$data[$a]=array_merge...`. хотя не уверен, что вы потом такую структуру в excel. Я бы скорее переделал на один запрос из обоих таблиц и потом как то эти данные развернул. Но для этого надо понимать требуемую структуру "многомерного массива"

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно используете функцию `array_merge`  В вашем случае она вообще не нужна.

Надо просто добавлять записи в массив c помощью конструкции `$arr[] = $value`.

```
 $dbname = array();
 //заполнение массива $dbname
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
 {
   $dbname[] = $row;
 }
 $data = array(); 
 for($i=0; $i < count($dbname);$i++)
 {
   $a = $dbname[3];
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT date, hours FROM first WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-02-1' AND '2016-02-10' and names = '$a'");

   while($wor = mysql_fetch_row($res))
   {
     $wor[] = $a;
     $data[] = $wor;
   }

 }
```

А в принципе задачу можно решить и с помощью одного запроса, и не обязательно даже делать его сложным.

UPD:

Так как строится запрос по всем сотрудникам, то имена отдельно можно и не выбирать. В этом случае задача сводится к следующему

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT date, hours, names FROM first WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-02-1' AND '2016-02-10'");
$data = array();

while($wor = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
     $name = $wor['names'];
     unset($wor['names'];
     if (!isset($data[$name]))
     {
       $data[$name] = array();
     }
     $data[$name][] = $wor;
}
```

Comment: попробовал так как вы предложили , массив с сотрудниками получается многомерный запрашивать элементы из него не очень удобно, там для каждой фамилии свой  массив, в моем варианте вот что получается " Array ( [0] => Иванов [1] => Васильев [2] => Петров [3] => Смирнов [4]" А пример запроса можно увидеть?

Comment: @Алексей дополнил ответ. Код не проверял - но должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо помогло, получаю и выгружаю данные)), не подскажете каким образом сделать выгрузку сразу за календарный месяц? как это сделать в запросе, чем заменить date 1 and date 2 and BETWEEN